# How to debug a code that does not give any error or enter the callback?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, debugging

I'm trying to understand why the debugger does not go into the callback function, it does not give any errors or any results... It just jump over connect.query!

When I run in the mySQL workbench the code runs and I get the data, so the query is not incorrect either.. (You can see the [example](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction) from the creator of the mysql node package, I can't understand why I can't get into the callback)

```
SELECT * FROM eclasstree WHERE numberofdigits = '8';
```

Here is the part of the code that does not enter the callback, all the other SQL queries works above works just fine...

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM eclasstree WHERE numberofdigits = '8'", function(error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                  throw error;
                }
                console.log(results, fields);
              });
```

index.js // route /generatewordsconnectedtoeclass

```
require("console-stamp")(console, "[HH:MM:ss.l]");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Database, mySQLConnectionDetails, connection } = require("../helpers/mySQL");
const { cleanseString, cleanseStringToArray, generateCountDuplication, sortValuesBykey, generateScoreArray, calculateAverage, replaceAbbreviationWithExpansion } = require("../helpers/stringFixers");

const database = new Database(mySQLConnectionDetails);


router.get("/generatewordsconnectedtoeclass", (req, res) => {
  const eClassArray = [];
  let eClassCode = "";

  connection.query("SELECT * FROM eclasstree WHERE numberofdigits = '8'", function(error, results, fields) {
    results.forEach(eclassobj => {
      eClassCode = eclassobj.code;

      connection.query(`SELECT itemnumber, cleanname, eclass FROM partnumbersclassified WHERE eclass = '${eclassobj.code}'`, function(error, results, fields) {
        let stringToArray = [];
        let countObject = [];

        if(results.length > 0) {
          stringToArray = cleanseStringToArray(results, "cleanname");
        }

        if(stringToArray.length > 0) {
          countObject = generateCountDuplication(stringToArray);
          // console.log(countObject);
          for (const property in countObject) {
            if (countObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              // console.log(property + " : " + countObject[property] + " : " + eClassCode);
              // console.log(property);
              // const obj = {
              //  eclasscode: `${eClassCode}`,
              //  wordcount: `${countObject[property]}`
              // };
              // obj[property] = `${countObject[property]}`;
              // const obj2 = obj;
              //              connection.query(`INSERT INTO wordsconnectedtoeclasscode (eclasscode, word, wordcount) VALUES (${eClassCode}, ${property}, ${countObject[property]})`, function(error, results, fields) {
              // const post = {word: "Hello", wordcount: "1"};
              // connection.connect();
              connection.query("SELECT * FROM eclasstree WHERE numberofdigits = '8'", function(error, results, fields) {
                if (error) {
                  throw error;
                }
                console.log(results, fields);
              });
              // connection.query("INSERT INTO posts SET ?", post, function(error, results, fields) {
              // //connection.query("INSERT INTO wordsconnectedtoeclasscode (eclasscode, word, wordcount) VALUES ('12345123', 'balle', '2'})", function(error, results, fields) {
              //   if (error) throw error;
              //   console.log(fields);
              //   console.log(results);
              //   connection.end();
              // });
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
  res.json({});
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image: I have breakpoint at the connection.query and also inside, but it does not go into the callback...]

If I do "step in-to" I can see the "sql" is defined with the query, but the "cb" is undefined!
[image]

Comment: How are you using the debugger? If you are using stepping that wont work as the call is async. You need to set a break point to some line inside the callback and let it run and the debugger should stop when it gets to the break point.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I doing that.. Please see updated post in the breakpoints.

Comment: That looks like you are stepping, hitting for instance "Step over function" or "Step into function" at the current point where the debugger is stopped you wont be able to enter from there. The call is async thus the callback is not called immediately. All current code has to complete before the engine will call it. You have to let it "Run" from that point instead of trying to step into it

Comment: @PatrickEvans I press the play button. I have tried to run the code without the debugger as well and it does not enter that callback as it does not console log the rows that I should have received back from the query as results..

Comment: Note in your last image query is defined to need 3 arguments, the query, the values, and then the callback, you passed the callback as the values argument, so call should be something like `connection.query('select...',null,function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

With help of @Patrick Evans I solved it.

I read up on the docs for the mysql node package and they do not follow the standard mysql queries. So after I changed it, it worked!

```
const obj = {
                eclasscode: `${eclassobj.code}`,
                wordcount: `${countObject[property]}`,
                word: property
              };
              connection.query("INSERT INTO wordsconnectedtoeclasscode SET ?", obj, function(error, results3) {
                if (error) {
                  throw error;
                }
                console.log(results3.insertId);
              });




require("console-stamp")(console, "[HH:MM:ss.l]");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Database, mySQLConnectionDetails, connection } = require("../helpers/mySQL");
const { cleanseString, cleanseStringToArray, generateCountDuplication, sortValuesBykey, generateScoreArray, calculateAverage, replaceAbbreviationWithExpansion } = require("../helpers/stringFixers");

const database = new Database(mySQLConnectionDetails);



router.get("/generatewordsconnectedtoeclass", (req, res) => {

  connection.query("SELECT * FROM eclasstree WHERE numberofdigits = '8'", function(error, results1) {
    results1.forEach(eclassobj => {
      connection.query(`SELECT itemnumber, cleanname, eclass FROM partnumbersclassified WHERE eclass = '${eclassobj.code}'`, function(error, results2) {
        let stringToArray = [];
        let countObject = [];

        if(results2.length > 0) {
          stringToArray = cleanseStringToArray(results2, "cleanname");
        }

        if(stringToArray.length > 0) {
          countObject = generateCountDuplication(stringToArray);
          for (const property in countObject) {
            if (countObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

              const obj = {
                eclasscode: `${eclassobj.code}`,
                wordcount: `${countObject[property]}`,
                word: property
              };
              connection.query("INSERT INTO wordsconnectedtoeclasscode SET ?", obj, function(error, results3) {
                if (error) {
                  throw error;
                }
                console.log(results3.insertId);
              });
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
    // res.json({});
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```